# How to disable registered OpenCL platforms on Windows?

Tags: registry, opencl, drivers

I am using OpenCL 2.0 on Windows. My machine has 2 platforms:

- CUDA GPU (with OpenCL 1.2)
- Intel CPU/GPU (with OpenCL 2.0)

I don't want OpenCL API to return the CUDA platform at all. According to this [article](http://streamcomputing.eu/blog/2015-08-14/opencl-basics-multiple-opencl-devices-with-the-icd/), opencl.dll returns the registered platforms by looking at Windows registry. However, there is no mention of which registry keys are searched for.

How can I disable a certain OpenCL driver/platform on Windows so that is not returned by the API?

Comment: What is your objective? Once OpenCL API returns both platforms, you can drop one by looking at platform info (clGetPlatformInfo() gives the vendor name). Please elaborate more if this approach does not suit your purpose

Comment: Yes, I can do that of course and this what I do now. But I am working on a code base as part of a team and I don't want to change the code for this case in particular and erroneously commit this to everyone else (if I forgot to undo that change before pushing). Because I am the only one in the team working with OpenCL 2.0 so far, other people don't want to do that check.

Comment: if your concern is to consider a device/platform specific to particular opencl version, then get the opencl version using clGetDeviceInfo() with flag "CL_DEVICE_OPENCL_C_VERSION". In your case, pickup the device with opencl2.0 version and proceed. Any accidental check-in doesn't cause any issue to your team in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you mention, the OpenCL ICD loader gets the list of available OpenCL platforms from the Windows registry. To prevent an OpenCL platform from appearing to any OpenCL application running on your system, you just need to remove the corresponding value from one or both of these registry keys:

For 32-bit machines or 64-bit apps on a 64-bit machine:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Khronos\OpenCL\Vendors`

For 32-bit apps on a 64-bit machine:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Khronos\OpenCL\Vendors`

The name of the registry value will be the full path to the `.dll` providing the OpenCL runtime implementation.

This is a fairly heavy-handed approach to solving the problem, in my opinion. Most OpenCL applications provide the user with a means to manually select/override the desired OpenCL platform (e.g. via a command-line argument, environment variable, or even if GUI if applicable).

Comment: This is a reasonable solution if you only want to hide the 1.2 platform on a single dev machine. I recommend saving out the Registry sub-tree so you can restore it later. As the comments in the question indicate, if you want this to happen on all machines, ignore the <2.0 platforms or devices in your code.